# How to reflect changes in client when database changes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend

So here's my scenario: I have a client page, where any one can fill and submit a form. the form data is stored in a database. There is a separate admin pc which is on an admin page, where every new form entry is displayed. How to update the front end of the admin everytime a new form is submitted, without refreshing/re hitting the API?

I am using React with express and MongoDB.

Comment: Refresh is not required if it's SPA, but how can you get info which is successfully* stored in Database without hitting it via api ??

Comment: @KcH ofcourse it will hit the API once, but what I mean was i didn't want it to refresh to update the content everytime there's a new entry. Note that the admin device and the form submitting devices are separate.

Comment: May be you may have to check server side events tmk ...

Comment: You should use web sockets for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can use TanStack Query (also called react query) ,

it's useQuery (a data fetching method) has a build-in property called isFetching which allow automatic fetching in a specific interval you want, like :

```
const { data,isLoading,isFetching } = useQuery(
   ['random-data'],
  async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://random-data-api.com/api/v1/random_data'
    );
    return data;
  },
  {
   // refetch data every sec.
    refetchInterval: 1000,
  }
);
```

you can check more [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/examples/react/auto-refetching)

Comment: does this re-hit the api every `refetchinterval` seconds?